# How to dynamically modify variables in PagingSource class, Paging Library 3.0

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack, android-paging

I have a livedata called **selectedModuleTab** which holds some variables like **filters**
I need to pass those filters to the data source repository **crmRepo** in order to fetch data from server.

I just started to use Paging Library 3.0 and i can't figure it out how to modify the **PagingSource class** every time my filters change.

I've tried to use Transformations but then i needed to create the **Pager** every time the filters change, this causes scroll position to be lost after returning to this view.

How can i modify the PageSource class every time a **livedata changed** (selectedModuleTab) ?

In my ViewModel I have this LiveData:

```
    val recordsList = Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 10),
    pagingSourceFactory = { RecordListPagingSource(crmRepo, selectedModuleTab.value) })
    .liveData
    .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

And this is my PageSource class:

```
    class RecordListPagingSource(private val crmRepo: CrmRepository, private val moduleTab: ModuleTab?) :
    PagingSource<Int, SmallRecordModel>() {
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, SmallRecordModel> {
        return try {
            val page = params.key ?: 0
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = crmRepo.getRecordsListFromModuleSuspended(
                    ACCOUNT_MODULE,
                    (page * 10),
                    moduleTab?.tabFilters,
                    moduleTab?.tabLayout
                ),
                prevKey = page - 1,
                nextKey = page + 1
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I'd do it is by making the `load` functionality outside of the `PagingSource`.

I don't know how your structure is, but this is how I did my similiar implemenation.

A ViewModel for each Tab, to hold the logic for loading the pages, and also keep the state of the paging related to only the tab. Or one `ViewModel` where you pass the filters, if the API (or function) is the same.
Then, change your `Paging Source` to take in a Suspended Function parameter, that knows tells the `Paging Source` how to load the data. Or, pass the Filter parameter into the `Paging Source` (assuming you went for the one-common `ViewModel`).

That way, each page knows what data needs to be loaded, and the `Paging Source` just loads the pages, while maintaining a common loading functionality.

From a personal experiance, go with the suspended function parameter, as it makes the PagingSource reusable independent of the page you are using, or even the kind of data.

---

P.S : If you're new to developing apps, or using a library, don't use the Alpha versions as sometimes they contain logic or features that are not completely finalized, as sometimes the functions or logic can change later.

Comment: Maybe implementing PagingSource in viewmodel ? 
My tabs are only filters presets so i didn't tought it would be necesary to have a different ViewModel for each.
I didn't understand how to pass the filter parameter into the PagingSource, since i can't observe livedata inside that class and invalidate it each time that data change.
About the suspend function parameter, i'm new to suspend functions and Kotlin coroutins and don't know what this means, but i will look up for it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem with a `RemoteMediator`, for which I was trying to change the parameters of its constructor for the network-call.

Being stupid, I assumed creating an anonymous instance in the `RemoteMediator` (or `PagingSource` in your case) during construction of the `Pager` is a must-given (like in the sample-code).

But you can simply expose the `PagingSource`/`RemoteMediator`-instance in your `Repository` or `ViewModel` and the `PagingSource`'s constructor-properties you want to change to be `public var`'s so you can change those properties before callling `refresh()` on the `PagingDataAdapter`.